# Change back button behavior

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, back-button

I have this activities structure in my android app (the arrow means that i'm pressing button that opens the next activity/fragment):

Activity A -> Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Activity B -> Fragment B

I want that when i press back button on last Fragment B it goes to Activity A, instead of Activity B. Is it possible?

It works only if i follow this path on my app:
Activity A -> Fragment A -> Fragment B

How to do that?

Comment: Check out the android developer site - [proper back navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) and [back navigation for fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

This actually happens in your current code. If you are at the last Fragment B (in Activity B) and pressed back, It takes you back to Activity A but with Fragment B loaded .. which is the state you navigated from when you went to Activity B.

To resolve this, you can use `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` in Activity A. And when the `onActivityResult` is called, hide Fragment B and show Fragment A.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `finish()` in the activity that you don't want to go back to (`finish()` kills the activity) or implement your own method to override the default. Hope this helps.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // New code
}
```